# sentence grammaticality? "47 cities were being supplied with piped gas"

Tags: grammar

Is this sentence grammatically correct:

> "47 cities were being supplied with piped gas"

Thank you

Comment: Why do you think it is ungrammatical?

Comment: It's grammatically OK, but stylistically inelegant. Replace the numerals "47" with the words "forty seven", and all will be fine.

Comment: Forty-seven should be hyphenated, according to some style guides.